# Android Studio set background image for all xmls

Tags: java, android, xml, background-image

I'm a beginner at Android Studio so I need to set background image for all pages. I know how to do it for only one page:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/mypic">
```

But how can I type this once and avoid typing for all the pages?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate `table_layout.xml` and then include that `layout` in every page.

**table_layout.xml**

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/mypic">
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    layout="@layout/table_layout" />

<Button
    android:layout_below="@id/table_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    />
```

Comment: Nice one but will I keep typing layout=..... for each page instead of typing background=....?

Comment: You will only include that layout `<include
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    layout="@layout/table_layout" />`

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it individually but if more than one attribute which is repeating you can make style of it. and use only that style.

Comment: The background line should be repeated only. Would you mind showing me a style example?